# How to give name to a dataTable Dynamically in c#?

Tags: c#

While splitting a Data Table into separate tables based on column, need to give name for separate table while splitting on the compile time.

Scenario #1:

Main DataTable:

```
col1    col2    col3    
9       3       5
```

DataTable1:

```
col1    col2
9        3
```

DataTable2:

```
col1    col3   
9       5
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you have tried and what is giving you the error?

Comment: What do you mean with "name"? You can set the attribute "name" of the DataTable when calling the constructor: new DataTable("Table name"). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Dynamically attribute name should be assigned to a table while loop through on splitting a main Data table into separate  tables based on the specified example. @Nebr

Comment: Main Table: Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
Name Mark1 Mark2 Mark3 Mark4
Peter 78 67 87 56
Smith 67 76 83 95
Phan 55 77 88 99
William 59 69 78 94
    
    
Need to Split as like below specified:    
Table 1:    
Name Mark1   
Peter 78   
Smith 67   
Phan 55   
William 59   
    
Table2:    
Name Mark2   
Peter 67   
Smith 76   
Phan 77   
William 69   
    
Table3:    
Name Mark3   
Peter 87   
Smith 83   
Phan 88   
William 78   
    
Table4    
Name Mark4   
Peter 56   
Smith 95   
Phan 99   
William 94